# recursive function to convert string to integer ML

Tags: recursion, sml, ml

I need to write my own recursive function in ML that somehow uses ord to convert a string of numbers to integer type. I can use helper functions, but apparently I should be able to do this without using one (according to my professor).

I can assume that the input is valid, and is a positive integer (in string type of course).

So, the call str2int ("1234") should output 1234: int

I assume I will need to use explode and implode at some point since ord operates on characters, and my input is a string. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what kind of help you need? Your assumption that *explode* and *ord* will be helpful is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a helper function `charsToInt` that processes the digits in the string from left to right.
At each step it converts the leftmost digit `c` into a number and does addition with the 10x-multiple of `n` (which is the intermediary sum of all previously parsed digits) ...

```
fun charsToInt ([], n) = n
  | charsToInt (c :: cs, n) = charsToInt (cs, 10*n  + ord c - 48)

val n = charsToInt (explode "1024", 0)
```

Gives you: `val n = 1024 : int`

As you see the trick is to pass the intermediary result down to the next step at each recursive call. This is a very common technique when dealing with these kind of problems.

Comment: That is much simpler than what I was able to come up with! Thank you! The final code I was able to write is below.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you asked, I guess I can [ruin all the fun](http://instructor.mstc.edu/instructor/swallerm/Struggle%20-%20Butterfly.htm) for you. This will solve your problem, but ironically, it won't help you.

Well, the ordinal number for the character `#'0'` is `48`. So, this means that if you subtract of any ordinal representing a digit the number 48 you get its decimal value. For instance

```
ord(#"9") - 48
```

Yields 9.

So, a function that takes a given character representing a number from 0-9 and turns it into the corresponding decimal is:

```
fun charToInt(c) = ord(c) - 48
```

Supposing you had a string of numbers like "2014". Then you can first explode the string into list of characters and then map every character to its corresponding decimal.

For instance

```
val num = "2014"
val digits = map charToInt (explode num)
```

The `explode` function is a helper function that takes a string and turn it into a list of characters.

And now `digits` would be a list of integers representing the decimal numbers `[2,0,1,4]`;

Then, all you need is to apply powers of 10 to obtain the final integer.

```
2 * 10 ^ 3 = 2000
0 * 10 ^ 2 = 0
1 * 10 ^ 1 = 10
4 * 10 ^ 0 = 4
```

The result would be `2000 + 0 + 10 + 4 = 2014`

Comment: that is what I figured had to be done, any idea how to do so recursively? That is the part I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```js
fun pow10 n =
    if n = 0 then 1 else 10*pow10(n-1);

fun str2help (L,n) =
    if null L then 0 
    else (ord(hd L)-48) * pow10(n) + str2help(tl L, n-1);

fun str2int (string) =
    str2help(explode string, size string -1);
    
str2int ("1234");
```

This gives me the correct result, though is clearly not the easiest way to get there.